# How to calculate hashcode of java hashset

Tags: java, collections

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

set.add("amit");
set.add("kushal");
set.add("vikas");
set.add("ravi");

Iterator<String> i=set.iterator();  
while(i.hasNext())  
{  
    System.out.println(i.next());  
}
```

// Output

```
kushal
ravi
amit
vikas
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and how it relates to the code in your question. You can just call `set.hashCode()` to obtain the hash code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print the hashCode of your HashSet by calling *hashCode()* function

```
 System.out.println("HashCode value: "+ set.hashCode());
```

Here *set* is your HashSet which has a function *hashCode* which is called.

> The hashCode() method of HashSet in Java is used to get the hashCode
> value for this instance of the HashSet. It returns an integer value
> which is the hashCode value for this instance of the HashSet.

Source: [More info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-hashcode-method-in-java-with-example/)